# Centos 7 isn't using my dedicated graphics card

Tags: centos, graphics, graphic-card

I recently purchased a thinkpad p50s and decided to put centos on, but now the computer is not using the dedicated nvidia card. How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you install the Nvidia driver? It is proprietary and you have to download it.

Comment: @Thomas I have downloaded it and gotten a .run file, but I am unsure of what to do with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the third party NVidia driver, I suggest you avoid using the .run file, and use the ELRepo repository.  Follow [these instructions](http://elrepo.org/tiki/tiki-index.php) to get the `nvidia-detect` package.  Then run `yum install $(nvidia-detect)`, which should install the appropriate driver on your system.

(`nvidia-detect` looks up which driver is appropriate for the hardware you have.)

Comment: Using the run file Xorg (startx for the Gnome environment) was completely destroyed and I had to do a fresh install. Do you have any experience with nvidia drivers and GNOME conflictions like that?

Comment: Not sure what you're saying. But it's not surprising that it overwrote packaged files. This is why we don't recommend using it.